# Roots of a two variable equation

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, irreducible-polynomials

What are the roots of the following equation: $a^4+b^4+(2×{a^2}×{b^2})-(a^6×{b^2}×{{100^4}\over2})+(a^5×{b}×{100^2})-(a^9×b×{{100^6}\over{36}})-(a^3×b^3×100^2)+(a^7×b×{{100^6}\over{36}})=0$

Comment: There are many roots, which ones do you want to be listed?

Comment: I want to calculate the first five roots of "a" and "b".